# How does Android do its spinner style with the triangle icon in the corner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I've spent way too much time researching this, but I'm wondering if anyone can provide any insight to how Android does its spinner styling with the triangle dropdown indicator?

[image]

The reason I want to know is that I am using a custom textview as spinner item, and once I use that I lose the triangle. In addition, I want to make the triangle white.

I've seen previous answers with modifying the theme but I don't want all spinners to change so I don't want to modify the entire theme. I want to learn how Android does the triangle so I can recreate it. I tried using a list-layout drawable with a triangle shape but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted. But you'll have to go through themes at some point, even for one particular (manually set in XML) Spinner.

Comment: It's just a 9 patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `drawbleEnd`

```
android:drawableEnd="@drawable/imgresource"
```

Answer (score 1):

create an image of how you want as your spinners background with whatever type or triangle and whichever color your want and then set that image as the background of your textview like this

```
android:background="@drawable/myBackground"
```

Answer (score 1):

It a simple [Nine Patch Drawable](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

You can create a NinePatch graphic, set a black dot on the top and left to expand the top and left edges. With a triangle in the bottom right.